# How to expand collapsed header bar on partial reverse scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to collapse my header bar when the page scrolls down, and expand it back to original size when I scroll up, but my question is how can I achieve this when I scroll up to some extent but not completely to the top position.

My html code is:

```
<div id="topbox">
    <div>
        some content
    </div>
    <div id="headerscroll">
        some content
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript code is:

```
var pagetop,headerscroll,ypos,topbox;
function yscroll() {

    pagetop = document.getElementById('pagetop');
    headerscroll = document.getElementById('headerscroll');
    topbox = document.getElementById('top-box');

    ypos=window.pageYOffset;
    if (ypos>150) {
        pagetop.style.height = "70px";      
        headerscroll.style.top="-15px";
        headerscroll.style.paddingBottom="5px";
    }
    else {  
        headerscroll.style.paddingBottom="20px";
        pagetop.style.height = "140px";
        headerscroll.style.top="32px";
    }
}

window.addEventListener("scroll",yscroll);
```

The problem is it only goes back to the original size when the scroll position is at the top, not on a partial scroll-up.

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should work just to make your function remember the previous ypos, and expand your header if it has reduced at all:

```
var pagetop,headerscroll,ypos,topbox, prevYpos;

function yscroll() {
    pagetop = document.getElementById('pagetop');
    headerscroll = document.getElementById('headerscroll');
    topbox = document.getElementById('top-box');

    ypos=window.pageYOffset;
    if(ypos>150 && ypos > prevYpos) {
        pagetop.style.height = "70px";
        headerscroll.style.top="-15px";
        headerscroll.style.paddingBottom="5px";
    } else {
        headerscroll.style.paddingBottom="20px";
        pagetop.style.height = "140px";
        headerscroll.style.top="32px";
    }
    prevYpos = ypos;
}

window.addEventListener("scroll",yscroll);
```

Here's a JS Fiddle that (roughly) illustrates this: https://jsfiddle.net/09Lxng5h/

Comment: Cool! I tidied up your question a bit too so that it's a bit clearer.

Comment: If it's working OK for you can you accept my answer and the question edits? Thanks!